# Content from EditText does not appear in TextView.

Tags: android

I am completely new in android but I thought I at lease learnt how to write simple code to have contents from EditText appear in the TextView. But seems like not. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance. Here is my code.

detailsActivity.java

```
public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText etTop;
    TextView tvTop;
    String cTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        //imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
        Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("id");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        etTop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTop);
        tvTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBottom);
        cTop = etTop.getText().toString();
        tvTop.setText(cTop);

    }
}
```

details_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#b72828">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/etTop"
        android:hint="Enter Top Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColorHint="#fdfdfd"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvBottom"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etBottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create"
        android:id="@+id/cButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/etBottom"
        android:hint="Enter Bottom Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColorHint="#fdfdfd"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvTop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etTop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason:**

```
cTop = etTop.getText().toString();
tvTop.setText(cTop);
```

gets executed as soon as activity is created. By this time you don't get any chance to enter any text in `EditText`. When yo do, this code has been already executed. So you need to get the text from `EditText` and set it into `TextView` when you actually enter the text.

**Solution:**

Remove above mentioned two lines of code and add this

```
etTop.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       tvTop.setText(s.toString());
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {}
});
```

Now every time you will change the text in `EditText`, `TextView` will be update automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used you code exactly like you said and it works.

Comment: @PinkeshS: If it helped you then please don't forget to accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
etTop.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               tvTop.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              //.. Or set it here if this is desired behavior
            }
        });
```

Your code doesn't listen for changes to the EditText instead your code is saying, go get me the text right now, instead of listening for text being added into the edit text.

So having said that drop these lines:

```
  cTop = etTop.getText().toString();
  tvTop.setText(cTop);
```

and add the above snippet of code in its place.

Good Luck and Happy Coding!